# HSC ASSESMENT - UICollectionView signal SIGABRT

Tags: uicollectionview, sigabrt

Okay, so i am building a basic UICollectoion view app in Xcode, going off of a tutorial on the Ray Wenderlich website, when I get to the point of running it, it searches for photos, and then i get an error with this line of code...

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FlickrCell " forIndexPath:indexPath]; //< error on this line
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        return cell;
```

}

What will fix this and allow the app to continue running?

Comment: what does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the trailing space in the identifier string.

```
"FlickrCell "
 ..........^
```

It should be "FlickerCell".